# Public struct inside a class and scopes

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following code in a header:

```
class A {
 public:
  struct B {...}
  ...
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to make this declaration in a source that includes the above header file:

```
 ...
B structb;
 ...
```

without having to declare the scope I'm using? `(A::B structb)`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A class is in this aspect similar to a namespace. You can get around using an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the code you have shown, it means that B is a struct that is inside A, like any other attribute of A. So, without the use of the scope resolution, you cannot declare the variable or use it.

Comment: but it is in the public part of A, so isn't it visible everywhere?

Comment: @PanagiotisFilianos  I think you have misunderstood the concept of OOP. A class attribute or method can be accessed only through its objects.

Comment: But what is the actual difference in declaring struct B as public then? Does this mean that if B isn't public, I can't even use the scope resolution operator to access it, in the way mentioned?

Comment: Exactly. B is public, so it can be accessed from anywhere in the code, using the object of A. If it is declared as private, it can be accessed  only from inside the functions of class A. If it is protected, it can be accessed from inside the functions of class A and any class that inherits from A

Comment: Thanks a lot. That actualy makes mycode more elegant than I thought it would be.

Comment: @PanagiotisFilianos Any time.. Happy I could help.. :-)

Comment: Just so you know, if you were to make this nested class private you'd still be able to, for example, return it from a public member function. You just couldn't _name_ it.